# Enumerable Join - Joining Two Lists

Tags: c#

I have two lists (List) with the the following data:

**List One**

```
James
Jack
Laura
Harry
```

**List Two**

```
Jeffery
Peters
Smith
```

Is it possible to do a Join, using Enumerable Join, to do the following:

```
James Jeffery
James Peters
James Smith
Jack Jeffery
Jack Peters
Jack Smith
Laura Jeffery
Laura Peters
Laura Smith
Harry Jeffery
Harry Peters
Harry Smith
Harry Jeffery
```

What type of Join of this?

Comment: That's at best a "cross join", otherwise known as two nested loops.

Comment: It's not a Join but a Product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a cross join:

```
List<string> textLines1 = new List<string>() {
    "Kames", "Jack", "Laura", "Harry"
};
List<string> textLines2 = new List<string>() {
    "Jeffery", "Peters", "Smith"
};

var query = from t1 in textLines1
            from t2 in textLines2
            select string.Format("{0} {1}", t1, t2);

var results = query.ToList();
```

Returns what you expect.

It can also be done using Method based query:

```
var query2 = textLines1.SelectMany(t1 => textLines2, (t1, t2) => string.Format("{0} {1}", t1, t2));

var results2 = query2.ToList();
```

Comment: Is this LINQ? Is it also possible without LINQ using textLines1.Join<>()?

Comment: `textLines1.Join<T>` is part of LINQ as well!

Answer (score 1):

In Linq it would be:

```
List<string> TabOne = new List<string>() { "Kames", "Jack", "Laura", "Harry" };
List<string> TabTwo = new List<string>() { "Jeffery", "Peters", "Smith" }; 

var combo = from p in TabOne
        from c in TabTwo
        select new
        {
            Name = p,
            SurName = c
        };
```

It is called a cross join.

Comment: Had to change one line of your code to get it running:             var combo = from p in TabOne from c in TabTwo select new { Name = p, Surname = c };

Answer (score 0):

```
var l1 = new []{ "James", "Jack", "Laura", "Harry" };
var l2 = new []{ "Jeffery", "Peters", "Smith" };

var result = from i1 in l1
             from i2 in l2
             select i1 + " " + i2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also known as `Cartesian Product` and Eric has a [blog post about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
var result = list1.SelectMany(i1 => list2.Select(i2 => i1 + " " + i2));
```

Example :

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] list1 = new[] { "James", "Jack", "Laura", "Harry" };
        string[] list2 = new[] { "Jeffery", "Peters", "Smith" };
        var result = list1.SelectMany(i1 => list2.Select(i2 => i1 + " " + i2));

        foreach (string s in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

App Output :

```
James Jeffery
James Peters
James Smith
Jack Jeffery
Jack Peters
Jack Smith
Laura Jeffery
Laura Peters
Laura Smith
Harry Jeffery
Harry Peters
Harry Smith
```